# UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Width and LayoutConstraint

Tags: swift

I get the following errors when I run the application. What kind of visual problem do I have ?

```
Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKitCore/UIView.h> may also be helpful.
2019-06-15 17:45:15.916490+0300 ...[3888:779219] [LayoutConstraints] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. 
    Try this: 
        (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; 
        (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. 
(
    "<SnapKit.LayoutConstraint:0x280cf51a0@MainTableViewController.swift#3209 ....DeviceTableViewCell:0x10c82cc00.width == 375.0>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x280be41e0 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Width' ....DeviceTableViewCell:0x10c82cc00'cellId'.width == 0   (active)>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<SnapKit.LayoutConstraint:0x280cf51a0@MainTableViewController.swift#3209 ...DeviceTableViewCell:0x10c82cc00.width == 375.0>

Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKitCore/UIView.h> may also be helpful.

 cell.snp.makeConstraints { (make) in
            make.top.equalTo(100)
            make.height.equalTo(205)
            make.width.equalTo(view.frame.width)
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you have 2 width constrains for the specific `cell`, so check that out.

- go to your storyboard.
- open the right side menu.
- On the top click the size inspector and check your constrains.

[image]

Or try to change the priority of your width constrain.

```
make.width.equalTo(view.frame.width).priority(999)
```

Comment: How do I design it to work on all devices? I have to change the width to what. Also thank you for your reply

Comment: I'm not using storyboard, I did it with visual code. I added the code to the subject.

Comment: How do I do that?

Comment: `make.width.equalTo(view.frame.width).priority(999)`